# How to configure Puma for a Hanami Application?

Tags: ruby, rack, puma, hanami, hanami-model

I have a Hanami 1.3.3 application which should run with Puma as production webserver. I want to use puma in cluster mode and use preload_app properly. Now I'm struggling with the right Puma config. I know, that every child-process (worker) must have its own fresh DB-connection, redis-connection, etc.
My application uses multiple db-connections, redis, sidekiq. The main db is handled via hanami-model, the other db's are handled with pg-gem (connections are set up at `class::initialize`) directly.

What's the right hanami-way to handle this?

Here's one approach:

```rb
workers 4
threads 1, 8

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        2300
environment 'production'

on_worker_boot do
  require_relative "config/environment"
  Hanami.boot
end
```

Is that correct? For me it does not feel right.

Is following better?

```rb
# ...
on_worker_boot do
  Hanami::Model.disconnect # but what happens to the opened db-connections of parent-process?
  Hanami::Model.load!
  # redis??
  # sidekiq??
end
```

Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of a fellow at [hanami/chat](https://gitter.im/hanami/chat), I ended up with following Puma config:

```rb
require_relative './environment'
workers 2

threads_count = 5
threads threads_count, threads_count

daemonize true

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        2300
environment 'production'

on_worker_boot do
  Hanami.boot
end
```

Here are infos which helped me to come to the conclusion:

[puma and rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot)

[definition of Hanami.boot](https://github.com/hanami/hanami/blob/master/lib/hanami.rb#L124)

[definition of Hanami.disconnect](https://github.com/hanami/model/blob/31566f1449a84c156b00188b785dc6aafd76416d/lib/hanami/model.rb#L84)